# How to get strings from h1 tags with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

```
<h1 align='center'>MD5 encrypt this string</h1><h3  
align='center'>pc08BLh9x7fCaZTHux9n</h3><center><form action="" 
method="post">
```

Please help me take the string in h3 tags!!
I tried this but got nothing:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C://Program Files//webdrivers//chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.gr/')

string=driver.find_element_by_tag_name(h3)
```

Comment: I don't know selenium, but shouldn't h3 be a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting the text of the h3 element then you need to do this:

```
string=driver.find_element_by_tag_name(h3).text
```

Answer (score 0):

h3 tag is not present on your site . so I have replaced that with a tag. please refer below solution to print associated with your tag

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chrome driver path")
driver.get('https://www.google.gr/')

string=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
print string.text
```

Also , if you want to retrieve text of all tags then you can use `find_elements_by_tag_name`. please refer below for the same.

```
string=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for element in string:
    print element.text
```